# Change monitor pixel dimensions using software on Windows 10

Tags: graphics-card, display-settings, display-driver, pixels

I have an Emerson LE220EM3 TV I am using for a second monitor.  The image it projects stretches about 65 pixels beyond the border of the casing.  For example, my taskbar and minimize/close buttons are cut off from view.  I want to adjust the display on the TV so that all elements on the screen are visible.

On my home computer, which runs Debian, I can simply call `xrandr` and adjust the scaling of a particular screen.  Unfortunately, my job requires Windows.  I can't find anything comparable to `xrandr` for Windows.

I am using Windows 10 on a Dell XPS 9560.  I have updated to the latest Intel HD Graphics driver available on the Dell website (26.20.100.7263).  Neither the Intel software nor the native Windows 10 display options seem to have an option to scale/adjust position.

There is a "PC Settings" section in the TV menu which is "unavailable" and greyed out.  I am connected using HDMI.  There is a VGA port on the TV labelled "PC".  Unfortunately, I cannot connect using VGA.  I have no VGA port on my laptop or docking station and I no VGA-to-X adapter.

Comment: Look in your TV settings for "overscan" and disable it. It is usually in the settings for that input.

Comment: That is a good suggestion.  Unfortunately, I don't see such an option.

Comment: If you have the Intel Graphics Control Panel installed you might have an option for underscan... https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-overscan-on-tv/

Comment: The setting for Underscan is in Intel Graphics Control Panel -> Display -> Custom Resolutions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4omuM.jpg

Comment: Thank you @1NN.  The Intel Graphics Control Panel is only detecting my built-in display.  NVIDIA only has options available for 3D.  NVIDIA is at latest (445.75).

Answer (score 0):

The following adjusts for the overscan at the cost of a lower resolution.

1. Go to "Display Settings" and select the offending display

[image]

2. Scroll down and click "Advanced display settings"

[image]

3. Click "Display adapter properties for display"

[image]

4. Press the "List All Modes" button

[image]

5. Select a different mode, press "OK", cross your fingers, and press "Apply".  Maybe you'll get lucky and the screen will fit to the display.  It did for me; YMMV.

[image]